# Nvidia GeForce 8600 GT resolution 640x480

Tags: drivers, nvidia, resolution

Just installed Ubuntu 12.10, I has 1024x768 resolution at first, than I add PPA

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

get update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and install driver

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

now I have 640x480 maximum.
How do I fix this? I'm newbie in Ubuntu, also not native english speaker, sorry for poor language and halp me, please.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Dash and search "nvidia." The program "Nvidia X Server" should appear. Open it and you should be able to set the resolution from that program.

Your English is excellent for not being a native speaker, by the way!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that something went wrong. I suggest reverting to the older package versions. Open a console and type line by line:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Please, follow the indications. After that, restart your system.